# How to gather all Gradle dependencies in Jenkins workspace

Tags: jenkins, gradle

There is a gradle project in git and there is a Jenkins job. What should be done:

1. The job checkouts project code from git.
2. The job starts gradle build: `sh "cd ${workspace}/${projectName}; ${workspace}/${projectName}/gradlew`
3. After that I want all project dependecies to be available right there in Jenkins workspace `${workspace}/${projectName}` in separate directory. Let's say `${workspace}/${projectName}/dependecies`

Of course there is no way to edit the project `gradle.build` files.

Could it be resolved by the `gradlew` command flags? Or should I add some init script: `${workspace}/${projectName}/gradlew --init-script /opt/myScript`. If so what it should contain?

Answer (score 0):

The point is to set Jenkins workspace as gradle.home. It solves by using of `--gradle-user-home` flag.
The final solution:

```
sh "rm -rf ${workspace}/${projectName}/caches"
sh "cd ${workspace}/${projectName}"
sh "chmod +x  ${workspace}/${projectName}/gradlew"
sh "${workspace}/${projectName}/gradlew build --gradle-user-home ${workspace}/${projectName}"
sh "zip -r -j ${workspace}/dependencies.zip ${workspace}/${projectName}/caches/modules-2/files-2.1"
```

All dependencies are stored in `caches/modules-2/files-2.1` directory now. For my needs I zip it to separate dependencies.zip file.